# How to add Safari End Script extension with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, safari, safari-extension

I'm trying to implement [the suggestion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/222721/how-to-avoid-hot-network-questions-on-the-sidebar#comment724813_222721) from another stackoverflow comment. I don't really need to be distracted by "Hot Network Questions" when I'm at work, and anyway this is an opportunity for me to learn how to make my first extension. To do this, I successfully built and installed an extension which just adds this End Script as Injected Extension Content to the domain `stackoverflow.com`:

```
$("#hot-network-questions").hide();
```

I can execute that in the console after a page load and it works as expected. When I load a `stackoverflow.com` page with the extension, I get this error:

```
ReferenceError: Can't find variable: $
```

I followed [this suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9626455/referenceerror-cant-find-variable):

```
jQuery("#hot-network-questions").hide();
```

But this gives me the error:

```
ReferenceError: Can't find variable: jQuery
```

I tried adding `jquery-1.11.0.min.js` as another Start/End script, but both of those emitted the same error. So clearly something about my script isn't formatted correctly, I just have no idea what. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19203216/injecting-jquery-to-webpage-from-safari-extension), but that seems too complicated to be the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

The problem may be caused because you included the jQuery library after the hiding script. Try to include first the jQuery library and after you custom script.